# Why can't I access this list generated in my method?

Tags: python, list, methods

I am trying to write a method that converts times given to just their digits (for easy integer conversion from hours to minutes). When I printed the generated lists within the method, it worked just fine.

However, when I try to access first_two_digits_list or last_two_digits_list from outside the method, it fails to do so (even with a global declaration).

Can someone explain to me why this happens, since I am not aware. Also, if anyone could help me find a solution or other way to access this list, that would be perfect!

```
times_list = [["11:00","12:00"], ["12:00","13:00"]]

# Method that converts list into sections of digits (for ease of integer use)
def ConvertToDigits():
    global first_value, second_value, third_value, fourth_value, last_two_digits_list

    # initial counter for while loop
    n = 0

    # two new lists of digits
    first_two_digits_list = []
    last_two_digits_list = []

    while n < len(times_list):
        first_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[0])[0]) + (((times_list[n])[0])[1]))
        second_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[1])[0]) + (((times_list[n])[1])[1]))

        third_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[0])[3]) + (((times_list[n])[0])[4]))
        fourth_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[1])[3]) + (((times_list[n])[1])[4]))

        first_two_digits_list.append([(first_digit_value), (second_digit_value)])
        last_two_digits_list.append([(third_digit_value), (fourth_digit_value)])

        n+= 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you didnt pass times_list  into ConvertToDigits as function parameters then return first_two_digits_list and last_two_digits_list from the function?  Although there are occasions when it's necessary, it is discouraged to have functions interact with variables in the global scope.

Comment: @DarrylG That is true. I will consider doing so.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `first_two_digits_list` or `last_two_digits_list` are **NOT** global variables. They're local variables of function `ConvertToDigits`. However, `times_list` is a global variable because it's defined outside the function and that's why you're able to access it within `ConvertToDigits`. A simple approach to solve your issue is this,

```py
times_list = [["11:00","12:00"], ["12:00","13:00"]]
# two new lists of digits
first_two_digits_list = []
last_two_digits_list = []
# Method that converts list into sections of digits (for ease of integer use)
def ConvertToDigits():
    # initial counter for while loop
    n = 0
    while n < len(times_list):
        first_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[0])[0]) + (((times_list[n])[0])[1]))
        second_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[1])[0]) + (((times_list[n])[1])[1]))
        third_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[0])[3]) + (((times_list[n])[0])[4]))
        fourth_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[1])[3]) + (((times_list[n])[1])[4]))
        first_two_digits_list.append([(first_digit_value), (second_digit_value)])
        last_two_digits_list.append([(third_digit_value), (fourth_digit_value)])
        n+= 1
ConvertToDigits()
print(first_two_digits_list,last_two_digits_list)
```

---

Output

```
[['11', '12'], ['12', '13']] [['00', '00'], ['00', '00']]
```

---

**Follow up from comments**

Another way to do it:

```py
times_list = [["11:00","12:00"], ["12:00","13:00"]]
# Method that converts list into sections of digits (for ease of integer use)
def ConvertToDigits():
    # initial counter for while loop
    global first_two_digits_list, last_two_digits_list
    first_two_digits_list = []
    last_two_digits_list = []
    n = 0
    while n < len(times_list):
        first_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[0])[0]) + (((times_list[n])[0])[1]))
        second_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[1])[0]) + (((times_list[n])[1])[1]))
        third_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[0])[3]) + (((times_list[n])[0])[4]))
        fourth_digit_value = ((((times_list[n])[1])[3]) + (((times_list[n])[1])[4]))
        first_two_digits_list.append([(first_digit_value), (second_digit_value)])
        last_two_digits_list.append([(third_digit_value), (fourth_digit_value)])
        n+= 1
ConvertToDigits()
print(first_two_digits_list,last_two_digits_list)
```

---

Output

```
[['11', '12'], ['12', '13']] [['00', '00'], ['00', '00']]
```

Comment: so I can't access the list within the method (even if I declare it to be global)? Has to be defined outside? Just want to know for future references.

Comment: If it's declared global(like in the example in my answer), it can be accessed anywhere(that's why we have global variables), inside or outside of the function. However, if it's defined within the function, you cannot access it outside the function(out of scope). You can however, return the list from function if you don't want to declare it as global and print the returned list.

Comment: I meant like if I specify that it is global inside of the function (as in global ...)

Comment: You can do it that way too. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah I guess something was wrong with my global declarations then. Thanks for the help